# Using onclicklistener dynamic image display

Tags: java, android, xml

This is my code for creating an app which displays next image when clicked on, I am having trouble creating a dynamic display, it crashes on clicking the image.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
     />
```

java file :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView im1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    im1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    im1.setImageResource(R.drawable.l);
    im1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            im1.setImageResource(R.drawable.m);
        }
    });
}

}
```

PS:originally in my XML file I was using `android:background="@drawable/l"`
to set my image at start

> log: 01-10 19:07:09.912
>   5465-5465/experiment.com.example.anurag.imageswap2 E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                           Process: experiment.com.example.anurag.imageswap2, PID: 5465
>                                                                                           java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 74649612 byte
>   allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 28MB until OOM
>                                                                                               at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
>                                                                                               at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>                                                                                               at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
>                                                                                               at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
>                                                                                               at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:806)
>                                                                                               at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:458)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(ContextCompatApi21.java:26)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:321)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:175)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:168)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:51)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:72)
>                                                                                               at
>   experiment.com.example.anurag.imageswap2.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:24)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: Would please provide the logcat?

Comment: The problem is out of memory, it looks like your image was 74 megabytes, why don't you resize your image and then try again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving your drawables from lower MPI to HDPI or to even higher dimension folders like XHDPI depending on your resolution.

Comment: thanks mate , didn't exactly knew the size drawable allowed will keep this one in mind

Comment: Try to find out more about `OutOfMemory` exception and I am pretty sure you will find your way out. You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This will improve the performance and avoiding the out of memory

```
<application      
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:largeHeap="true">
```

Add these lines in manifest